# What transformations have been applied to this image to yield four derivatives?

Tags: image-processing, homework

In a few days I have an exam of image processing. I'm currently having a look at the example exam and I came across this question. "Which transformation of this image is being done here. Explain the components in the quadrants NA (second image)."

[image][image]Na

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Had this question on my exam. And the answer given here was that answer that i used. The answer was correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This to me looks exactly like the two-dimensional [Haar wavelet transform](http://cam.mathlab.stthomas.edu/wavelets/pdffiles/NewOrleans07/HaarTransform.pdf). All four quadrants are a part of the transform, even though different operations have been performed on them. Upper left quadrant is a result of low-pass filtering with a 2x2 two-dimensional rect function (Haar wavelet) and decimation be a factor of 2, upper right is the output of a horizontal high-pass filter, lower left is the output of a vertical high-pass filter, and lower right is the output of a diagonal high-pass filter.

Comment: I had this question on my exam. I really hope you are correct :p

Comment: Well, that's what I would have put down. On the other hand, I have no idea what your professor might have called it. Haar wavelet transform, however, is the most common name. Let me know how it goes! = ) Also, what is the subject you're studying?

Comment: Engineering with multimedia and information technology major. We saw the haar wavelet transform. And from what I've studied, this seems to be correct. :D